# Restrict special characters in android password edittext

Tags: java, android, regex, validation, android-edittext

I am working on a project where the user is allowed to type only password with **letters**, **alphabets** and special characters like (**@.#$%^&*_-&**) alone in a edittext. I tried various methods like. **Note**: space is strictly restricted

**Method 1:**

setting digits in layout as follows

**android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,*@#$%_-\^.&<qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"**

This method is working fine but i could able to type **brackets**'(', **semicolon** ';' and i could not type **slash** '\' (which i have added in the digits tag)

**Method 2:**

By trying regex with following method

```
public static boolean limitPasswordCharacters(String about){
        // UserName Validation Pattern String
        final Pattern USER_NAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9@.#$%^&*_&\\]+$");
        if(USER_NAME_PATTERN.matcher(about).matches()){
            return true;            
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But unfortunately gettting exception as

```
11-17 16:18:11.155: E/AndroidRuntime(15877): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Missing closing bracket in character class near index 22:
11-17 16:18:11.155: E/AndroidRuntime(15877): [a-zA-Z0-9@.#$%^&*_&\]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your pattern like below,

```
final Pattern USER_NAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9@.#$%^&*_&\\\\]+$");
```

In java regex, to mean a backslash, you need to escape it three times. Java consider this `\\]` as a lietral `]` bracket.

Example:

```
String digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,*@#$%_-\\^.&<qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
System.out.println(digits.matches("^[-a-zA-Z0-9@.#$%^&*_&,<\\\\]+$")); //true
```

Comment: sure, take your time.

Comment: avinash everything is working but slash (\) not working in the regex

Comment: could you explain the above comment? Wow, you from Chennai?

Comment: did you want to allow a backslash?

Comment: also space should be restricted

Comment: you mean, the password must contain atleast a single backslash? Could you post some examples for valid and invalid strings?

Comment: Could you post some examples for valid and invalid strings?

Comment: valid chandru@123, chandru\123, chandru#123, #chadn@%^&*123

Comment: In valid chandru 123, chandru:123, chandru!123, chandru/123

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65072/discussion-between-chandru-and-avinash-raj).

Answer (score 1):

Simply paste this line in your edittext

```
android:digits="0123456789qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm "
```